# Class of file uploading to S3 using boto with multipart supported

Tags: python, error-handling, logging, flask, amazon-web-services

I'm writing an app by Flask with a feature to upload large file to S3 and made a class to handle this.

I have some targets in writing code:

- Code must be easy to understand and maintain. (Yes, everyone wants this, so do I)
- Logs should be as detail as possible, especially when working with S3. I want to have detail logs when something go wrong.
- File type (mime) must be detected and written to file object on S3.
- Large file will be uploaded by [multi parts](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_multipart_upload).

Basically, it's working for my case but I want to hear your advice/comments about the way I'm doing, especially in some points: logging, exception handling, docstring, function/variables naming, everything you see it's not pythonic way.

Edit1: have one aceepted answer but others are welcome :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import logging

import magic
import boto3 as boto
import botocore

from Flask import abort


class S3(object):
    '''
    Handle request and write to S3
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.bucket = 'my_bucket'
        self.conn = boto.resource('s3')
        self.client = boto.client('s3')
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + self.__class__.__name__)

    @staticmethod
    def mime(fheader):
        '''
        Detect mime type by reading file header.
        fheader: first bytes to read
        '''
        return magic.from_buffer(fheader, mime=True)

    def upload(self, path, req):
        '''
        Directly upload file to s3. Use this for small file size
        path: object path on s3
        req: request object contains file data. (req = request.files['file'])
        '''
        fheader = req.read(1024)
        mime = self.mime(fheader)
        body = fheader + req.read()
        disposition = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(path))
        try:
            self.logger.info('Trying to upload {}'.format(path))
            resp = self.conn.Object(self.bucket, path).put(
                Body=body,
                ContentType=mime,
                ContentDisposition=disposition
                )
            if resp['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
                self.logger.info('{} uploaded to S3'.format(path))
                return True
            else:
                self.logger.error('Failed to upload {} to S3. Detail: \n{} '.format(path, resp))
                return False
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:
            self.logger.critical('S3 connection error', exc_info=True)

    def upload_multipart(self, path, req, psize=1024*1024*5):
        '''
        Upload multipart to s3
        path: object path on s3
        req: request object contains file data.
        psize: size of each part. Default is 5MB.
        '''
        # only need first 1024 bytes for mime()
        fheader = req.read(1024)
        mime = self.mime(fheader)
        disposition = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(path))
        try:
            # initialize multipart upload
            self.logger.debug('Initializing multipart upload for {}'.format(path))
            mpu = self.client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=self.bucket,
                                                      Key=path,
                                                      ContentType=mime,
                                                      ContentDisposition=disposition
                                                      )
            self.logger.debug('Initialization of {} success with info: {}'.format(path, mpu))
            part = 0
            part_info = {
                'Parts': [
                    ]
            }
            self.logger.debug('Start uploading parts to {}'.format(path))
            while True:
                body = req.read(psize)
                if body:
                    part += 1
                    if part == 1:
                        body = fheader + body
                    self.logger.debug('Uploading part no {} of {}'.format(part, path))
                    resp = self.client.upload_part(Bucket=self.bucket,
                                                   Body=body,
                                                   Key=path,
                                                   PartNumber=part,
                                                   UploadId=mpu['UploadId']
                                                   )
                    self.logger.debug('Part {} of {} uploaded.'.format(part, path))
                    part_info['Parts'].append(
                        {
                            'ETag': resp['ETag'],
                            'PartNumber': part
                        }
                    )
                    self.logger.debug('Part {} of {} info: {}'.format(part, path, part_info))
                else:
                    break
            self.logger.info('Multipart upload {} finished. Start completing...'.format(path))
            # complete the multipart upload
            self.client.complete_multipart_upload(Bucket=self.bucket,
                                                  Key=path,
                                                  MultipartUpload=part_info,
                                                  UploadId=mpu['UploadId']
                                                  )
            self.logger.info('Multipart upload completed!')
            return True
        except:
            self.logger.error('Failed to upload file {}'.format(path), exc_info=True)
            if mpu:
                self.logger.info('Aborting the upload of {}...'.format(path))
                self.client.abort_multipart_upload(
                    Bucket=self.bucket,
                    Key=path,
                    UploadId=mpu['UploadId'])
                self.logger.info('Upload of {} aborted!'.format(path))

    def exists(self, path):
        '''
        Send a HEAD request to see if object exists.
        If object exists, return its Metadata. Otherwise return HTTP 404 code
        path: object path to check existence
        '''
        try:
            resp = self.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket,
                                           Key=path)
            return resp['ResponseMetadata']
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == '404':
                abort(404)

    def download(self, path):
        '''
        Download an object from bucket.
        This method shoud be used for development only.
        path: object path to download
        '''
        if self.exists(path):
            self.logger.info('{} downloaded from S3'.format(path))
            # TODO: avoid reading all in once
            return self.conn.Object(self.bucket, path).get()['Body'].read()

    def info(self, path):
        '''
        Get metadata of object and return as a dict
        path: object path to get metadata
        '''
        info = dict()
        resp = self.exists(path)
        if resp:
            headers = resp['HTTPHeaders']
            info['content_length'] = headers['content-length']
            info['content_type'] = headers['content-type']
            self.logger.info('Retrieved info of {} from S3.'.format(path))
            return info
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of minor, but you wrote:

```
while True:
    body = req.read(psize)
    if body:
        ...
    else:
        break
```

which causes the entirety of `...` to be indented.  If you slightly restructure to:

```
while True:
    body = req.read(psize)
    if not body: break
    ...
```

then the `...` block can be dedented a level, making it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code. Your comment makes sense, it's more easier to read.